# Can starting day be set up using cronj4?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, cron4j

Using cron4j, one can set up a job to run in some time in a future

```
    Scheduler s = new Scheduler();
    s.schedule("5 10 * * *", job);
    s.start();
```

Using cron4j, can the job be scheduled to start "next Saturday", or on "12/21/2012"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  For example:

```
0 0 21 12 *
```

This says run this at 12:00 AM on December 21st.

The Chron syntax does not finitely support a year setting, but if you set this job today, it would run the next time it crosses that date.

Note: The other answer suggests adding a year column.  If you do include this, the behavior is  not entirely predictable -- it depends which chron implementation you're using.

Answer (score 2):

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

This is the basic break down of the command structure. starting something one the 21 would look like

0 0 21 12 *

But this would only run on the 21 of the 12 month every year.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can define the year but since the fields are `minute hour day month day_of_week (year)` you should be able to at least let the job run at 12/21/2012 using this expression: `0 0 21 12 ? 2012`.

Edit: cron4j doesn't seem to support the optional year expression, so it seems you can just define `0 0 21 12 *` and have the job run every December 21st.